# How to send a body request with GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, api, get

I'm working with angularjs, and from my service I have to make a call to the server using a path parameter (id), query params (var1 and var2) **and a body request** ({"codes": ["1000"]}) - which has to be sent as an string array, within a get method (I know, sending a body request should be done within a POST).

So far, in my service I have this:

```
        function getSub(id, var1, var2) {
           var payload = {
               first: var1,
               second: var2
           };

           var url = 'sub/' + id + '/mylink'
           return api.get(url, payload, {"codes": ["1000"]}).then(function (response) {
               console.log("READ RESPONSE ", response);
               return response;
           });
        };
```

So far, all I am getting is a bad request error linked to the response body not provided.

It may be a noob question, and not a best practice one, but I meed to find a solution for this. So far, by searching the net far and wide, I could only understand that this is an unorthodox way of using body request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can send a request body with GET but it  make no sense. you can parse it on the server and modify your response based on its contents, you are ignore this recommendation in the [HTTP / 1.1 specification, section 4.3:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the standard has no statement about the body of a `get` type request. Thus this is a classical *it depends on the implementation*. Anyway, implementations tend not to support such a combination. And [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) is one of them:

> send() accepts an optional parameter which lets you specify the request's body; this is primarily used for requests such as PUT. If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to null.

Comment: The weird part is, that, in firefox, in Network, if I click on the 500 get request, in headers click on Edit and resend, I have there a field called Request Body, and if I put my {"codes": ["1000"]} there, and press resend, it will turn into a 200 request (given that I add in the request headers Content-Type: application/json).

Comment: Yes, because it is using some native component for it, not the one exposed to the JavaScript engine. And it looks that your server is supporting this feature. You can try using `fetch api` (https://www.ma-no.org/en/content/index_fetch-api-an-amazing-replacement-of-xmlhttprequest-ajax_2203.php), but you might well face cross-browser issues with that. If you succeed this api, you have to see if you can live just with that. But better try to get the server code updated...

Comment: Yup, you were right. It's getting changed on server side to post. Thanks! This was of great help!

Comment: That is not correct. The standard is quite clear: "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1

Comment: @EricStein, just read your comment and my post again, and you will see that I wrote much the same. Ok, you'r right, there is a sentence about it, but that does not change the fact, that there is no mandatory statement: it is neither prohibited nor supported. You might face problems like OP, and you might not, it depends on the implementation. And that is far from being _clear_...